# HOW to do - click on submit button opens hyperlink with parameter from option in perl cgi

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi

On a CGI page(opened from index.html), this is the sample code ->

```
while (@row = $sth2->fetchrow_array()) {  # retrieve one row
print <<eoh1;    
    <option value=$row[0]>$row[0]</option> #Say it fills option values 1,2,3
eoh1
 }

print <<eoh2;
<input type="submit" name="get" value="Go">
 </select>
eoh2
```

Now from drop-down, user selects 2, so it should open www.xyz.com/2 in a new window.
Plz help...i m a novice in perl cgi and need to submit this asap :(

Answer (score 1):

Given that the value of the selected option is the url in question you could do something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="open(this.url.value,'','');return false;">
<select name="url">
<option value ="http://url1">1</option>
<option value ="http://url2">2</option>
<option value ="http://url3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="get" value="Go">
</form>
```

you can see it running  here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fgk7s/

Answer (score 1):

The following is a solution that does not use Javascript.  Using Javascript might give you other options.

You need to write another script that is the action target of your form:

```
print <<eoh0;
<form name="myForm" action="otherScript.pl" type="get" target="_blank">
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
eoh0

while (@row = $sth2->fetchrow_array()) {  # retrieve one row
print <<eoh1;    
    <option value="$row[0]">$row[0]</option> #Say it fills option values 1,2,3
eoh1
 }

print <<eoh2;
 </select>
<input type="submit" name="get" value="Go">
</form>
eoh2
```

In otherScript.pl, you use CGI to get your arguments.

```
use CGI;

my $co = new cGI;
my $arg = co->param("mySelect");

$co->redirect("/$arg");
```

Check out the CGI [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) for more information on parameters and redirects.

Comment: thnx a ton for the reply...made suggested changes...
when i select option 1 and click on Go button...it opens page https://blah.com/raj/other.pl?mySelect=1&get=Go&mySelect=2&get=Go&mySelect=3&get=Go...but it should have opened xyz.com/1...
i wrote $co->redirect("/$arg"); as $co->redirect("xyz.com/$arg");

plz help...

Comment: Hm...what is the value of `$arg`?